# Intermittent wrong date from time.strftime()

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have an Appengine app that still runs on the python2.5 runtime, which means it is single threaded. I have a school class:

```
class School(db.Model):
    ...
    dateformat=db.StringProperty(default='%a %e %b',indexed=False) # For bookings
    timeformat=db.StringProperty(default='%l:%M%P',indexed=False) # For bookings
    def date(self,t):
        return time.strftime(self.dateformat,time.gmtime(t))
    def datetime(self,bt,et=None):
        return time.strftime(self.dateformat+' '+self.timeformat,time.gmtime(bt))+\
                (time.strftime(' - '+self.timeformat,time.gmtime(et)) if et else '')
    def time(self,t):
        return time.strftime(self.timeformat,time.gmtime(t))
```

Then when I want to format a date in the school's chosen format, I do this:

```
s=School.get_by_id(the_id)
date_string=s.date(the_timestamp)
```

Very occasionally, I get a date that is exactly a week out. So instead of "Wed 2 May" I get "Wed 9 May". This has been reported three times in the last week, out of probably tens of thousands of cases. All *exactly* a week out, none with any other time difference.

Nothing's changed in that part of my code for ages so I don't understand why this should suddenly start happening. Because it's single threaded, there shouldn't be issues with strftime, and I can't find any reports of thread issues with it anyway anyway.

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like the code is fine; the part of the code you pasted doesn't seem particularly relevant. Assuming that strftime and gmtime work fine (I've no reason to doubt them -- especially since gmtime uses libc's gmtime -- and App Engine doesn't do anything special with them.) The real question is, where does `the_timestamp` come from? I'm betting that `the_timestamp` is a week out, nothing to do with the conversion or formatting.

Comment: Good point, but the_timestamp comes from a semi-permanent member of a school object - it doesn't change over time, and it is used very frequently. It's hard to see how this could intermittently return 604800 more than usual.

Comment: Then perhaps you could share the code you use to extract `the_timestamp` from the datastore? Maybe something's going on over there. It's going to be hard to solve this one on just this information (and I do appreciate how hard it is to debug an issue when all you have is intermittent reports of it going wrong, and nothing solid to go on...)

Comment: It's a simple get_by_id() - no processing, simply read the property. If the get_by_id() were somehow corrupting data, I'd expect other properties to be munted too.